# Powershell using call operator on 7zip

Tags: powershell

## Intro

So, I'm attempting to read in a zip file from a directory, and unzip that to a tmp location.  The problem is that powershell seems to be misinterpreting the quotes and not writing out the value of the $copyLocation variable.  Instead, it is copying the files to [currentDirectory]\$copyLocation.  I'm hoping you all can help.  I'm new to Powershell, and this is only a piece of the script I have to write to take over our build automation.  Thank you in advance.

By the way, hosts is an XmlElement which we are iterating over.  So, we're deploying this zip file to a location on a number of hosts specified in an xml configuration file.

```
function copyWebappToDestination($copyWebappFrom,$to,$hosts){
foreach( $it in $hosts ){
    Write-Host "Deploying webapp" $webapps.webappName "to" $it.hostIp "at" $it.to

    setUpDirectories

    foreach($file in $filelocation){
        if($file.name.ToString() -eq "Web.Main.zip"){
            $filename = $file.name.ToString()
            $hostIp = $it.hostIp
            $fileDest = $file.FullName
            #unzip the files
            & '7z' x ""$fileDest"" -o""$copyLocation"" -y -r
            break
        }
    }
}
```

## Edit

The weirdest part, is that I wrote out the command

```
& '7z' x "C:\MoveToProduction\SM\PROD\Web.Main.zip" -o"C:\MoveToProduction\SM\PROD\tmp" -y -r"
```

And ran that from a Powershell console, and it worked just fine.  It just doesn't work from within the context of a script.

## Edit Final

So, I gave up trying to get the call operator working.  Basically, what I ended up settling on was the command:

```
Invoke-Expression -command  "cmd /C '7z x `"$fileDest`" -o`"$copyLocation`" -y -r'"
```

Comment: I think you want `& 7z "C:\MoveToProduction\SM\PROD\Web.Main.zip" "-oC:\MoveToProduction\SM\PROD\tmp" -y -r`

Comment: Not sure if it helps but Ive had great luck with [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) with powershell.  Might be easier.

Comment: May this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180346/script-to-create-archive-using-powershell-and-7zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I gave up trying to get the call operator working. Basically, what I ended up settling on was the command:

```
Invoke-Expression -command  "cmd /C '7z x `"$fileDest`" -o`"$copyLocation`" -y -r'"
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap -o in the quote

```
$tz = "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe"
set-alias sz $tz
$source="c:\users\user\test\*.tar
$dest="c:\users\user\test2be"

sz x "$source" "-o$dest" -y
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit after comments :

Another thing you should try is using a single pair of double quotes to wrap all the 7z arguments

Initial answer

Try to use $($copylocation.FullName) to have the full path of your destination directory

When you use $copylocation which is a DirectoryInfo, Powershell use the ToString method of the object which happens to give the directory name only, not the full path

Comment: It actually doesn't give the directory name, though.  That's the problem.  It copies the files to the directory $copyLocation.

Comment: I understand now... Have you tried not to double your double quotes ?

Comment: Another thing you should try is using a single pair of double quotes to wrap all the 7z arguments

Comment: And with a set if double quotes enclosing $filedest and another enclosing -o....  ?